Application of Chain Rule in Proof of Stokes' Theorem
In the proof of Stokes' theorem in "Vector Calculus" by Marsden and Tromba, I noticed that the chain rule is applied selectively. Specifically, the chain rule is not used when expanding the curl components $\nabla \times \mathbf{F}$ in terms of partial derivatives with respect to $x$, $y$, and $z$. However, later in the proof, the chain rule is applied when using Green's Theorem.
Stokes' Theorem Statement:
Stokes' Theorem states that for a vector field $\mathbf{F}$ and a surface $S$ with boundary $\partial S$:
$$
\int_{\partial S} \mathbf{F} \cdot d\mathbf{s} = \int_S (\nabla \times \mathbf{F}) \cdot d\mathbf{S}.
$$
Parameterization:
The surface $S$ is parameterized by $(u, v)$ with $\mathbf{r}(u, v) = (x(u, v), y(u, v), z(u, v))$. The boundary $\partial S$ is parameterized by $t$ with $\mathbf{r}(t) = (x(t), y(t), z(x(t), y(t)))$.
The curl of $\mathbf{F} = F_1 \mathbf{i} + F_2 \mathbf{j} + F_3 \mathbf{k}$ is given by:
$$
\nabla \times \mathbf{F} = \left( \frac{\partial F_3}{\partial y} - \frac{\partial F_2}{\partial z} \right) \mathbf{i} + \left( \frac{\partial F_1}{\partial z} - \frac{\partial F_3}{\partial x} \right) \mathbf{j} + \left( \frac{\partial F_2}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial F_1}{\partial y} \right) \mathbf{k}.
$$
Applying Green's Theorem:
To convert the line integral around $\partial S$ to a double integral over $S$, we use Green's Theorem in the plane:
$$
\oint_{\partial D} \left( P \, dx + Q \, dy \right) = \iint_D \left( \frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial P}{\partial y} \right) \, dx \, dy,
$$
where $D$ is the projection of $S$ onto the $xy$-plane.
Chain Rule Application:
When applying Green's Theorem, we need to express $F_1, F_2,$ and $F_3$ in terms of $x$ and $y$. For instance, we use the chain rule to account for the dependence of $F_1, F_2,$ and $F_3$ on $x$, $y$, and $z$:
$$
\frac{\partial F_2}{\partial x} \rightarrow \frac{\partial F_2}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial F_2}{\partial z} \frac{\partial z}{\partial x}.
$$
Question:
Why is the chain rule not used initially for terms like $\frac{\partial F_2}{\partial x}$ when expanding $\nabla \times \mathbf{F}$, but later in the proof, it is used when applying Green's Theorem to handle terms involving mixed dependencies, such as $\frac{\partial F_2}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial F_2}{\partial z} \frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$? Could someone provide a detailed explanation of the reasoning behind this selective application of the chain rule in the proof of Stokes' Theorem?

Because you parametrize the surface in order to compute the surface integral as a double integral. At that point, you must parametrize $\partial S$ and turn the line integral into an integral over $\partial D$. Now, applying Green's Theorem, you compute the partial derivatives, but here $z$ has become a function of $x$ and $y$. Not earlier.

Actually, I assumed the surface was given by $z=f(x,y)$, but it looks like a general parametrization in terms of $u,v$, so Green’s Theorem should be written in the $uv$-plane and the chain rule used to find the $u$ and $v$ derivatives of the composite functions.

Make sure to make the difference between partial and full derivative when applying the chain rule in Chain Rule Application.

Thank you, Ted Shifrin. This clears my confusion out.. Very helpfull.
